# On click of button not filtering array like intended

Tags: reactjs

Can someone explain to me why the filter method isn't working as intended? I am trying to update my array of objects with filtered results based on the first name.

```
export default function App() {
  const { data } = useDataFetcher();
  const searchArray = data;

  const [inputField, setInputField] = useState("");

  const searchUser = () => {
      searchArray.filter((el) => el.firstName.includes(inputField));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    searchUser();
  }, [inputField]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Xaxis Frontend Interview</h1>

      <input onChange={(e) => setInputField(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={(e) => searchUser()}> Search </button>

      {searchArray.map((userData, i) => (
        <Users
          key={i}
          firstName={userData.firstName}
          lastName={userData.lastName}
          email={userData.email}
          bio={userData.bio}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What is the _exptected_ result, and what do you _get_ instead? Please provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a state which will contain the list of the users. Then, you  want to update this state when `inputField` state changes.

```
export default function App() {
  const { data } = useDataFetcher();
  const searchArray = data;

  const [users, setUsers] = useState([])
  const [inputField, setInputField] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
    setUsers(data);
  }, [data]);

  useEffect(() => {
     const filteredArray = users.filter((el) => el.firstName.includes(inputField));
    setUsers(filteredArray)
  }, [inputField]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Xaxis Frontend Interview</h1>

      <input onChange={(e) => setInputField(e.target.value)} />

      {users.map((userData, i) => (
        <Users
          key={i}
          firstName={userData.firstName}
          lastName={userData.lastName}
          email={userData.email}
          bio={userData.bio}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Or if you want to update the list of users by clicking a button:

```
export default function App() {
  const { data } = useDataFetcher();
  const searchArray = data;

  const [users, setUsers] = useState([])
  const [inputField, setInputField] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
    setUsers(data);
  }, [data]);


  const searchUser = () => {
      const filteredArray = users.filter((el) => el.firstName.includes(inputField));
setUsers(filteredArray)
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Xaxis Frontend Interview</h1>

      <input onChange={(e) => setInputField(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={() => searchUser()}> Search </button>
      {users.map((userData, i) => (
        <Users
          key={i}
          firstName={userData.firstName}
          lastName={userData.lastName}
          email={userData.email}
          bio={userData.bio}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```